# Why does XCode switch the profile from automatically selected one to the iOS Team Profile

Tags: iphone, icloud, provisioning-profile

I have a problem where I have the appropriate signing profile selected in the build settings but when I run the app on the iPhone from Xcode I get the entitlements error. When I check the embedded mobile provision it has used the iOS Team Profile and not the one selected in the build settings.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much nashing of teeth and hair pulling finally tracked down the cause of this, dont you just love xcode error msgs. Although the correct mobile provision was automatically selected in Debug line of the code signing section, the sub selection line "Any iOS SDK" had the team profile selected somehow. Changing this to match the automatic selection solved the problem.